# Не могу вытащить текст из базы данных

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Пишу бота который отправляет погоду. Я подключил бд (sqlite3) для хранения telegram id и города человека с этим id. Если коротко, то после "/start" пользователь нажимает кнопку "Let's remember my city" а после сообщения бота вводит название города (язык ввода (en-ru) не имеет значения) дальше он заносится в базу и уже следующей функцией выводится погода. Однако функция уходит в exept и бот присылает сообщение "Oops I don't know this city...". Если не сложно подскажите почему оно не может достать город из базы. Спасибо

```
import telebot # module for telegram
from telebot import types # need for keyboard

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен_бота", parse_mode = None) # variable with bot and "TOKEN"

import pyowm # module for weather
from pyowm import OWM # I don't know (need to work module)
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config #special for ru language

config_dict = get_default_config()# special for ru language
config_dict['language'] = 'en'# special for different languages

owm = OWM('API_сайта') # is my API-key from openweathermap.org
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

import sqlite3 # special for create db

conn = sqlite3.connect("users_cities") # connect with this db
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_cities(
    id INTEGER,
    user_city TEXT,
    user_graphic TEXT);""")

conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) # handler for 1st message
def send_welcome(message):
    
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Let's remember my city") # keyboard for 1st memorize a city
    markup.add(button1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''' Hi, this is a bot created 
    to make your life easier. 
    With my help, you will 
    be able to find out the 
    weather without distracting 
    from your correspondence. 
    The only thing you should 
    know is that I am controlled 
    using my keyboard, when you 
    need to use a regular keyboard, 
    I will inform you.'''.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup) # sending the message for new user


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message): # all messages and commands hanler
    
    print(message.text)

    if (message.text == "Let's remember my city") or (message.text == "change city"): # handler for know city or rewrite it
        
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Write the name of your city')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_city) # need to know user's city

    elif (message.text == 'weather now'): # handler for weather
        weather_at_city_now( bot, message)

    elif (message.text == "⚙️"): # handler for settings
        
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("set up a schedule") # keyboard
        markup.add(button1)
        button2 = types.KeyboardButton("") # keyboard
        button3 = types.KeyboardButton("change city") # keyboard
        markup.add(button2, button3)
        button4 = types.KeyboardButton("change the amount of information") # keyboard
        markup.add(button4)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'You have entered the settings'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

    elif (message.text == ''):
        
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("weather now") # keyboard
        button2 = types.KeyboardButton("⚙️") # keyboard
        markup.add(button1, button2)
        button3 = types.KeyboardButton("weather tomorrow") # keyboard
        markup.add(button3)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'You are back in the main menu'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

    else: # handler for else...
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Я твоя не понимать')

def user_city(message): # function for simple way to know user city

    user_id = message.chat.id

    city = message.text

    conn = sqlite3.connect("users_cities") # connect with this db
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    info = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users_cities WHERE id=?', (user_id, ))

    if info.fetchone() is None: 
        
        conn = sqlite3.connect("users_cities") # connect with this db
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        sql = """INSERT INTO users_cities VALUES (?, ?, '0')"""
        data = (user_id, city)

        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        conn.commit()
    
    else:

        conn = sqlite3.connect("users_cities") # connect with this db
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        sql = '''UPDATE users_cities SET user_city = ? WHERE id = ?'''
        data = (city, user_id)
        
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        conn.commit()

    weather_at_city_now(bot, message)


def weather_at_city_now(bot, message): # function for simple way to weather
    
    try:
        user_id = message.chat.id

        conn = sqlite3.connect("users_cities") # connect with this db
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        city = str(cursor.execute('SELECT user_city FROM users_cities WHERE id = ?').fetchone()[(user_id)])

        observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city) # I don't know (need to work module)
        w = observation.weather # variable with weather
        
        w_detailed_status = w.detailed_status # clouds
        w_wind_speed = w.wind()['speed'] # wind speed
        w_wind_deg = w.wind()['deg'] # wind degree
        
        if w_wind_deg == 0:
            w_wind_deg = 'N (North⬆️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 45:
            w_wind_deg = 'NE (North-East↗️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 90:
            w_wind_deg = 'E (East➡️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 135:
            w_wind_deg = 'SE (South-East↘️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 180:
            w_wind_deg = 'S (South⬇️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 225:
            w_wind_deg = 'SW (South-West↙️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 270:
            w_wind_deg = 'W (West⬅️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 315:
            w_wind_deg = 'NW (North-West↖️)'
        elif w_wind_deg <= 360:
            w_wind_deg = 'N (North⬆️)'

        w_humidity = w.humidity # humidity

        w_max_temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp_max'] # max temp
        w_min_temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp_min'] # min temp
        w_temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp'] # now temp

        w_clouds = w.clouds

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("weather now") # keyboard
        button2 = types.KeyboardButton("⚙️") # keyboard
        markup.add(button1, button2)
        button3 = types.KeyboardButton("weather tomorrow") # keyboard
        markup.add(button3)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''status: {w_detailed_status}
        wind speed: {w_wind_speed}
        wind degree: {w_wind_deg}
        humidity: {w_humidity}
        min temp: {w_min_temp}
        max temp: {w_max_temp}
        real temp: {w_temp}
        clouds: {w_clouds}'''.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Oops I don't know this city...")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"try again")

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Write the name of your city')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_city) # need to know users city

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: сделайте `except Exception as e` и `print(e)` и посмотрите что за ошибка

Comment: я чтото не вижу строчки которая достает чтото из базы и ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Без подробностей о выброшенном исключении действительно сложно судить о проблеме, но, полагаю, точка отказа где-то в районе строки:

```
city = str(cursor.execute('SELECT user_city FROM users_cities WHERE id = ?').fetchone()[(user_id)])
```

Здесь в функцию execute передаётся лишь один параметр - сам запрос, в то время, как должен быть ещё и кортеж с параметрами запроса (user_id в вашем случае):

```py
In [9]: city = str(cursor.execute('SELECT user_city FROM users_citie
   ...: s WHERE id = ?').fetchone()[(123456)])
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-efeb74cbd120> in <module>
----> 1 city = str(cursor.execute('SELECT user_city FROM users_cities WHERE id = ?').fetchone()[(123456)])

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

Более корректный вариант получения города из базы:

```py
In [12]: city = cursor.execute('SELECT user_city FROM users_cities W
    ...: HERE id = ?', (123456,)).fetchone()

In [13]: city
Out[13]: ('Moscow',)
```

Обратите внимание, что набор параметров запроса передаётся кортежем, не смотря на то, что фактически параметр там один - `(123456,)`